# saving and retrieving bitmap

Tags: java, android

First Excuse me for my bad English.

I want to take/pick image from camera/gallery for displaying it in a layout and save it. and after closing the programme and reopening it again, I want to retrieve it.

So far I got here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView img_logo;
protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
protected static final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 1;
private Intent pictureActionIntent = null;
Bitmap bitmap;
String selectedImagePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img_logo= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img_logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startDialog();
        }
    });

}
protected void startDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
    myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                    pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                    pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,
                            GALLERY_PICTURE);
                }
            });

    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,
                            CAMERA_REQUEST);

                }
            });
    myAlertDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                // our BitmapDrawable for the thumbnail
                BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = null;
                // try to retrieve the image using the data from the intent
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(),
                        null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null) {

                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.DATA);
                    String fileSrc = cursor.getString(idx);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc); // load
                                                                        // preview
                                                                        // image
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                            100, 100, false);
                    // bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapPreview);
                    img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {

                    bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), data
                            .getData().getPath());
                    img_logo.setImageDrawable(bmpDrawable);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.hasExtra("data")) {

                // retrieve the bitmap from the intent
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");


 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                        .query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[] {
                                        Media.DATA,
                                        Media.DATE_ADDED,
                                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
                                Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
                        selectedImagePath = uri.toString();
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    cursor.close();
                }

                Log.e("path of the image from camera ====> ",
                        selectedImagePath);


                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100,
                        100, false);
                // update the image view with the bitmap
                img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else if (data.getExtras() == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No extras to retrieve!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                BitmapDrawable thumbnail = new BitmapDrawable(
                        getResources(), data.getData().getPath());

                // update the image view with the newly created drawable
                img_logo.setImageDrawable(thumbnail);

            }

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


}
}



}
```

It's working fine in pick or take, But it's not saving.
I know that I should save the Image Paths in Shared-preferences and then restore it again, But HOW?

If You could Just edit my code and Do what I want that would be awesome.
If not just give me some information.
Thank you So Much.